# How to set which page app opens on tap of GCM push notification

Tags: php, android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an API service in PHP that needs to send push notifications through GCM to client devices. I have everything set up and have an idea of how to do this but not sure of a few things.

1.Suppose the app has to open the page of a particular post when a notification is tapped, is there anything I have to set on the server while sending the notification? Like a link, etc?

2.Also, I'll be setting collapse keys in the notifications. Is it possible for the app the retrieve these collapse keys when notifications are opened so that the app can make an api call to let the service know the notifications have been read?

I do not have any knowledge of android but I would like to know what possibilities are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to First Point :** You need to just catch the extra bundle value(s) (ex. a post_id referring to particular post) from gcm to android and pass that value to the activity that you want to open and there you can make a call to a PHP file or web service requesting data to that particular post_id.

**Answer to Second Point :** yes you can get the values of collapse keys in android to handled in IntentService.
I am just telling you the way to get it :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String collapse_key = extras.getString("collapse_key");
```

after that you can normally use switch case to handle intents for different collapse keys.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think that's all I wanted to know.